# Extract parts of a string using a Regular Expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to extract the `first_name` and `second_name` strings but with this regex only get the `first_name` string.

```sql
SELECT
   SUBSTRING (
      'a:2:{i:0;s:14:"first_name";i:1;s:15:"second_name";}',
      '\"[^\"]*\" '
   ) as obs_regex
```

How do I modify my regex to get `first_name second_name` as the result?

thanks you

Comment: I would use `split_part()` for that

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You may match multiple occurrences using `g` flag and you need to use a capturing group to get the values without quoation marks:

```
SELECT
   REGEXP_MATCHES (
      'a:2:{i:0;s:14:"first_name";i:1;s:15:"second_name";}',
      '"([^"]*)"', 'g'
   ) as obs_regex
```

Result:

[image]

To get a concatenated string of matches you need to "convert" the `regexp_matches` result to an array and use `array_to_string`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING (
 ARRAY (
   SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES (
      'a:2:{i:0;s:14:"first_name";i:1;s:15:"second_name";}',
      '"([^"]*)"', 'g'
   )
 ), ' ') as obs_regex
```

Result:

[image]